# Display all data fetched, api rest using __next

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint

I need to fetch all data from an xml link but I couldn't as it displays only 300 rows, so I found a solution that says I should use __next, I have the code below but it doesn't work, in the console I get the next url but the items (TaskName) of the first page. I want to get the TaskName(s) of the next pages.

```
window.addEventListener('load',function() {

$.ajax({url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Tasks", 

                                        method: "GET",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        headers: {Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"},       
                                        success: function(data) { 
                                        var dataResults = data.d.results;
                                        if (data.d.__next) {
                                        url = data.d.__next;
                                        console.log("url: "+url);
                                        }                                       





        $.each(dataResults, function(key, value) 
                {                 
                    var tasky = value.TaskName;
                    console.log(tasky);
                });
        }});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, here the code is:

```
 function GetListItems(){


        $.ajax({
            url: urly,  
            method: "GET",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
            },
            success: function(data){
                response = response.concat(data.d.results);
                if (data.d.__next) {
                    urly = data.d.__next;
                    GetListItems();
                }
                $.each(response, function(key, value) 
                {                 
                    var tasky = value.TaskName;
                    console.log(tasky);
                });
            },
            error: function(error){

            }
        });
    }
```